# Remove trailing dot in URL domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

We have URLs of the form:

`www.dev-studio.co.uk.`

`www.dev-studio.co.uk./a-sample-image`

With the help of .htaccess rules, I am trying to remove the trailing dot (co.uk`.`) in the end of the domain name but I'm failing.

This is the rule I'm trying:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9\.-]+)(\.co\.uk\.)(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.dev-studio.co.uk/%3 [L,R=302,NE]
```

But the `%3` which should capture the 3rd group is returning empty.

The goal is to simple redirect `www.dev-studio.co.uk./a-sample-image` to `www.dev-studio.co.uk/a-sample-image`

I have tried all the other questions over here but the solutions are not working for me.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd suspect Apache is normalizing HTTP_HOST before it gets to your rewrite rules.

Comment: @ceejayoz, any suggestions?

Comment: Fix the URLs in the pages that use that syntax, or just ignore it. Is this actually causing you a problem of some kind?

Comment: Yes it is, we use 3rd party services that treat the 2 URLs differently. So if the FQDN is accessed, then it exposes sensitive info.

Comment: You should fix *that* security hole rather than trying to put a bandaid on it.

Comment: As I said, it's a 3rd party service and we're limited to what we're allowed to change.

Comment: You should be getting rid of a third-party service who considers an unexpected HTTP_HOST value to be reason to expose sensitive data to the internet.

Comment: _“But the %3 which should capture the 3rd group is returning empty.”_ - you matched the hostname up to and including `www.dev-studio.co.uk.` with `^([a-z0-9\.-]+)(\.co\.uk\.)` already - so what are you expecting `(.*)` after that to capture now? There _is_ nothing more.

Comment: @04FS If the URL has the request_uri, that can be captured with `(.*)` ?

Comment: Not in the `HTTP_HOST` value, because that _is not_ the full URL.

Comment: If you want to capture the _path_ of the requested URL and append it, then do that in the RewriteRule. `RewriteRule (.*) http://www.dev-studio.co.uk/$1 [L,R=302,NE]`

Comment: Ah yes, that's a mistake on my part. thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9\.-]+)(\.co\.uk\.)(.*)$
> RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.co.uk/%3 [L,R=302,NE]
> ```

The `HTTP_HOST` server variable contains the hostname only (ie. the value of the `Host` HTTP request header), it does not contain the URL-path, so the `%3` backreference is always empty.

You need to either capture the URL-path from the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. For example:

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.co.uk/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Or, use the `REQUEST_URI` server variable (which contains the full URL-path, including slash prefix) instead:

```
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

This should ultimately be a 301 (permanent) redirect, once you have confirmed it works OK.

Note that since you are redirecting to a specific domain, do you need a *CondPattern* that matches *any* `.co.uk` hostname? You could be specific:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.example.co.uk.
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

The `=` prefix on the *CondPattern* changes it to a lexicographical string comparison (not a regex), so no need to escape the dots.

If you wanted an entirely generic solution to remove the trailing `.` (FQDN) from any requested host then you could do something like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.+)\.$
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

Although you might want to combine this with your canonical redirects (eg. non-www to www / HTTP to HTTPS?) to avoid multiple redirects - although they are probably unlikely to occur all at once anyway, so probably not an issue.

Comment: Make sure you've put this redirect at the top of your `.htaccess` file, before any other rewrites. And clear your browser cache. The `REQUEST_URI` contains the full URL-path that is requested (unless you have conflicting rules that rewrite the request first). An alternative is to write: `RewriteRule (.*) http://%1/$1 [R=302,L]` - using a backreference instead. Although, if this in the root `.htaccess` file then the result should be the same.

Comment: I added the rules at the top and it worked! I didn't see your comment, thanks a lot Sir.